# How to render $createElement in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, createelement

I didn't find any documentation on `$createElement` in nuxt.

I tried using the following code to create an HTML Element:

```js
const elem = this.$createElement('h' + this.hlevel)
elem.text = this.myTitle
console.log('My Element:', elem)
```

Result is an object but I do not know how to render it.

Is it really to create an HTML Element or should this be used for a different use case?

Comment: `createElement` is basically an alias to `h`, you can read more about it here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx Those are aimed towards highly customizable dynamic markup generation. If you don't need that (or you issue could be solved with a dynamic component for example), it may probably be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createElement` is basically an alias to `h`, you can read more about it here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx.

Those are aimed towards highly customizable dynamic markup generation. If you don't need that (or you issue could be solved with a dynamic component for example), it may probably be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```js
render() {
  return this.$createElement('h' + this.hlevel, this.myTitle)
},
```

Also make sure you don't have

```html
<template></template>
```

as this will overwrite `render()`.

**Note:** as kissu commented, the use of `h()` or `$createElement()` is probably overkill :)